# Receive & Output JSON Error Message Android

Tags: java, android, json, list, hashmap

I have created an API for the purpose to retrieve data from database. Now I able to retrieve status, message and data from the API no matter I input the credentials correct or incorrect. There are two version of output. I used POSTMan to test on and that it seems working but when I try on Android, success message is okay but not the error one.

```
@POST
@Path("/appdatas")
public Response getSAppData(AppDataRequest adr) {
    Response data = ads.getSAppData(adr.getId(), adr.getEmail(), adr.getPassword());
    return data;
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public Response getSAppData(int id, String email, String password){
    Map<String, AppData> AppDataHM = new HashMap<String, AppData>(); 
    Map<String, Data> DataHM1 = new HashMap<String, Data>();
    Map<String, List<String>> DataHM2 = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
    Map ADHMDHM = new HashMap<>();

    Data data = DataHM.get(new AppDataRequest (id, email, password));
    List<String> message = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> data2 = new ArrayList<>();

    if(data != null){
        message.add("");
        AppDataHM.put("AppData", new AppData("success", message));
        DataHM1.put("Data", data);
        ADHMDHM.putAll(AppDataHM);
        ADHMDHM.putAll(DataHM1);
        String ADHMDHM1 = new Gson().toJson(ADHMDHM);
        return Response.status(200).entity(ADHMDHM1).build();
    }
    else{
        message.add("Your login information is invalid. Please try with the correct information");
        AppDataHM.put("AppData", new AppData("error", message));
        DataHM2.put("Data", data2);
        ADHMDHM.putAll(AppDataHM);
        ADHMDHM.putAll(DataHM2);
        String ADHMDHM2 = new Gson().toJson(ADHMDHM);
        return Response.status(500).entity(ADHMDHM2).build();
    }   
}
```

When I use POSTMan, I able to retrieve both output.

```
{
  "AppData": {
  "status": "success",
  "message": [
  ""
    ]
  },
  "Data": {
    "token": "token1"
  }
}

{
  "AppData": {
    "status": "error",
    "message": [
      "Your login information is invalid. Please try with the correct information"
    ]
  },
  "Data": []
}
```

When I apply the following code on Android, I able to retrieve data for success one but not the error one.

```
private void makeJsonObjectRequest(){
    showpDialog();

    String id1 = mEditTextID.getText().toString();
    String email1 = mEditTextEmail.getText().toString().trim();
    String password1 = mEditTextPassword.getText().toString();

    HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    params.put("id", id1);
    params.put("email", email1);
    params.put("password", password1);

    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(url, new JSONObject(params), new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {
                JSONObject AppData = response.getJSONObject("AppData");
                String status = AppData.getString("status");
                String message = AppData.getString("message");
                //JSONObject Data = response.getJSONObject("Data");
                //String token = Data.getString("token");

                jsonResponse = "";
                jsonResponse += "Status: " + status + "\n";
                jsonResponse += "\n";
                jsonResponse += "Message: " + message + "\n";
                //jsonResponse += "\n";
                //jsonResponse += "Token: " + token + "\n";

                mTextViewMain.setText(jsonResponse);
                hidepDialog();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                        "Error: " + e.getMessage(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            hidepDialog();
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error1: " + error.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                    "Error2: " + error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            hidepDialog();
        }
    });
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(request);
}
```

[image: Success]

[image: Error]

How possible I can get the output as shown in the 'error' output and display in the TextView?

Thanks for everyone for viewing this question.

Comment: String message = AppData.getString("message"); this is not string, this is jsonArray.

Comment: Have you print message string before set in TextView

Comment: Did any answer help?

Comment: Hi. @KuldeepKulkarni Thanks for your comment. I have tried both getString and getJSONArray method and they are both working for me.

Comment: Hi. @Chetan Thanks for your comment also. What is means by print the message string? Can you please help to elaborate more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you returning status 500 in your script? Volley assumes code 500 as error

```
return Response.status(500).entity(ADHMDHM2).build();
```

Try changing it to 200 and check

Comment: Hi. @Niruplyer Thanks for your reply. Your reply do solve my problem. Now, I facing problem of how possible I can display an empty array on TextView? Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [link](http://jsonutils.com/) to generate concrete classes for the json. Once you have the concrete classes then you can use [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) to convert json text to class. This way you will have concrete json to class mapping.
May be this can help.

Comment: Hi. @AshwaniK Is your "concrete classes" similar to TODO class? If you are talking about the "classes" for Java, I already have it in my Java program but my Android program don't have. Should I add the "concrete classes" to my Android program?

Comment: Concrete classes mean to which you want to convert your json reponse to. Generally it helps to have classes mapping to json for better readability and maintainability.

Answer (score 0):

**For `Message` try this:**

```
JSONArray messageArray = AppData.getJSONArray("message");
String message = messageArray.toString();
```

Comment: Hi. @FerdousAhamed I tried both getString and getJSONArray and they both working and give me the same expected output. This code maybe not solve my problem but it do help me to make my code better as I replace all my toString code for array to toJSONArray. Thanks for your help. Now I facing prob of displaying empty array. Could you possible help me on that?